# Can't lookup words in RStudio (Mac version)

Tags: r

In older RStudio versions, I was able to lookup words or directly Google search selected sentences, just like in the Safari browser. This is extremely helpful for me as a beginner and a non-native-English speaker. But I couldn't do so now and I wonder if the functionality is still there in the newest RStudio (Version 1.3.959).

Thank you.

Comment: RStudio doesn't do that as far as I'm aware. Do you mean this was code you had running in R?

Comment: @Phil I did have a memory using right click to lookup in Mac dictionary or send to Google Search. Mostly used in the "Help" tab, but also worked for the code in the Editor or Console. But right now whenever you do a right click, it only pops up "Copy-Paste-Select All-Reload-Inspect Elements" where it used to show additional "Look-up" and "Google Search" bottoms.